# How to calculate time complexity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

You have a binary tree with n elements that is not in sorted order.  What is the time complexity to find the smallest value?  Explain.

Say I have a binary tree of  5 is the parent of siblings (2 (left) and 6 (right)) and 2 is the parent of siblings 1 and 8.

Comment: 2 Things:
1. Welcome to MSE! it is highly recommended to show some effort (here and in other forums).
2. I believe that this question should be asked in other forum.

Hint: The minimum will be the leaf on the left most path in your tree.

Comment: This question should be migrated to http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

As the tree is *not* sorted, the tree representation is a red-herring: to find the least element, you can't binary search, and every element has to be examined, in both the best and worst cases. It's no different than if the values were stored unsorted in an array. If there are $n$ nodes then you must make $n-1 = \Theta(n)$ comparisons.